# Catalyst Not Accepting DBIx Generated Schema

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using [Catalyst::Plugin::AutoCRUD](http://search.cpan.org/~oliver/Catalyst-Plugin-AutoCRUD-2.120250/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/AutoCRUD.pm#TROUBLESHOOTING) and am generating a DBIx schema using the instructions provided in the linked CPAN page.  Specifically, I copy/pasted the command listed there and changed only the details relevant to my database ('pg' => 'mysql', different username/pw, etc).

I now have a schema DBIC::Database::foo::Schema.  Schema is both a file containing *.pm's for each table in my DB and also it's own Schema.pm.

My config file contains the following entry:

```
<Model::AutoCRUD::DBIC>
  schema_class   Database::foo::Schema
  connect_info   dbi:mysql:dbname=foo
  connect_info   user
  connect_info   pass
  <connect_info>
      AutoCommit      1
  </connect_info>
</Model::AutoCRUD::DBIC>
```

When I go to start the AutoCRUD server, I get the following error message:

```
Couldn't instantiate component "DemoApp::Model::AutoCRUD::DBIC", "Attribute (schema_class)
does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for
'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema::Types::SchemaClass' with value Database::foo::Schema at
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm line 1275.
```

As I am new to Catalyst and this plugin, I don't know how to resolve this issue.  Google has not been very helpful - I found [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/catalyst/users/26953) discussion, but from what I can tell the issue was that Catalyst was being pointed towards the wrong *.pm (although I could be misreading this).

In case this is helpful, here are the contents of Schema.pm:

```
use utf8;
package DBIC::Database::foo::Schema;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07024 @ 2012-05-20 07:25:21
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:cevz/k4rUWIcEhMl29r0QA


# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on  regeneration
1;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely rebuilding the DBIC classes from the [Catalyst manual](http://search.cpan.org/~zarquon/Catalyst-Manual-5.9004/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/03_MoreCatalystBasics.pod#Create_Static_DBIx%3a%3aClass_Schema_Files) solved the problem.  While I cannot pinpoint what was unacceptable to Moose in the first set of classes, the second set of classes had one additional problem: the line `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;` was generated for every class (i.e. in each *.pm).  Commenting it out and restarting Catalyst yielded a functioning CRUD app.

Answer (score 2):

Your schema is named `DBIC::Database::Foo::Schema` but in the config file you have `Database::foo::Schema`. The names are case sensitive so either change the name of your Schema path and files or correct the config.

Comment: Thank you!  That was a typo in writing this article.